# Two class methods, same name, different signatures: How to force compiler to use intended one?

Tags: objective-c, gcc

How do I force the compiler to select the desired method from a set of *class* methods sharing the same name?

```
/* Use +[MyClass port](UInt16 (*)(id, SEL),
 * not +[NSPort port](NSPort *(*)(id, SEL)). */
UInt16 port = [[self class] port];
```

I have an Objective-C class with a class method:

```
+ (UInt16)port;
```

`NSPort` has a convenience constructor whose signature conflicts with this:

```
+ (NSPort *)port;
```

Sending `+port` to my class results in a compiler warning:

```
UInt16 port = [[self class] port];
    W: Multiple methods named '+port' found
    W: Using '+(NSPort *)port'
    W: Also found '+(UInt16)port'
```

Fail: The compiler has chosen the wrong method signature.

Type inference fail: Using `[[(MyClass *)self class] port]` does not cadge it into using the right method.

***ETA:*** Here is the workaround I am using for now:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

Class c = [self class];
SEL s = @selector(port);
typedef UInt16 (*PortIMP)(id, SEL);
PortIMP MyClassGetPort = (PortIMP)class_getMethodImplementation(c, s);
UInt16 port = MyClassGetPort(c, s);
```

It is good in that:

- It handles dispatching to any subclass implementation correctly.
- It is confined to the implementation file, so this ugliness is not inflicted on anyone but the implementer.

It is bad in that it won't help anyone else who wants to call the method.

Comment: What is the relationship between MyClass & NSPort ?

Comment: @egarcia: There is no relationship. The `NSPort` header is imported by the Foundation framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just rename the method?  (lame, I know) You could argue that a method named "port" should be returning a port object (which is what `NSPort` does), and that if you wanted to return a primitive "port number", you'd call it "portValue" (a la "intValue", "longLongValue", etc).

Comment: Renaming the method doesn't solve the problem, it avoids it. Also, a survey of Apple framework usage confirms my intuition that a `port` method returning an integer type is thoroughly idiomatic: `-[NSURL port]` returns `NSNumber`, but `-[MIDINetworkHost port]` returns `NSUInteger`, `-[NSNetService port]` returns `NSInteger` so it can use -1 to mean "unresolved", and `-[NSMachPort machPort]` returns `uint32_t`. That's 3 methods ending in "port" returning scalar types versus 1 returning an object type.

Comment: Yes, this is avoiding the problem (hence the "lame, i know" comment).  The other examples you cited can be avoided by strictly typing the variables (since they're all instance methods). Your issue stems from the fact that this is a *class* method, and there doesn't appear a way to cast an `id` to a specific `Class`.

Comment: Selecting this answer because it is the most maintainable and frictionless solution. The root problem seems to be that Obj-C treats classes as second-class citizens in its object-oriented republic.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting… there doesn’t seem to be an obvious solution to this one.

You could use a protocol to declare the methods you need, for instance

```
@protocol MyClassProtocol
@optional 
- (UInt16)port;
@end
```

then do

```
UInt16 port = [(id <MyClassProtocol>)[self class] port];
```

Not pretty, but it does work.

Comment: I think you want that to be `+(UInt16)port;`.

Comment: No, it really does need to be `-(UInt16)port`, because you’re telling the compiler what methods the _class_ object has.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This likely works, which is an improvement over what I had before. The downside is that it pollutes the global protocol namespace. It's also ugly. I feel this is like forcing everyone viewing the header to watch a loud he-said–she-said argument between the Obj-C language and the GCC compiler.

Comment: Agreed, it’s ugly.  The only alternative I can think of is to declare a class with the correct method signature (as an instance method) and cast to that, but that suffers from the same namespace pollution problem and is in many respects an even bigger lie to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `[(MyClass*)[self class] port]`. This will work in all cases and is the simplest way.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work.  I had this idea too, but the compiler ends up wanting a `-[MyClass port]` method instead of a `+[MyClass port]` method, and it still produces a warning.

Comment: Odd, I can't say I've run into that edge case of this before.

Comment: The problem is that it’s a _class_ method. `[(MyClass *)[self class] port]` is telling the compiler that `[self class]` is an object of class `MyClass`, which is not correct.  Unfortunately, there's no syntax to express `[(<class of MyClass> *)[self class] port]`, which is why you need to use a protocol or declare a class with the correct method signature.